# Omitting arguments in C++ Templates

Tags: c++, templates

Is it ok to omit the type after the function name when calling a template function?

As an example, consider the function below:

```cpp
template<typename T>
void f(T var){...}
```

Is it ok to simply call it like this:

```cpp
int x = 5;  
f(x);
```

Or do I *have* to include the type?

```cpp
int x = 5;  
f<int>(x);
```

Comment: Couldn't you just try it and see what happens?  Seems easy enough to test.

Comment: @ Ed Swangren, The "just try it" method is very uninformative.  At best it tells you that a particular compiler allows the given syntax.  It tells you nothing about the semantics or correctness of the statement with regards to the language standard.

Comment: I suppose I could have clarified the question.  As Trent kindly pointed out, it wasn't so much of if this will compile.  I am curious about what's going on behind the scenes and having a hard time finding good information out there!

Comment: @Chris: I don't think the answer you accepted is very good information. It doesn't really even make sense, and it leaves out many details.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Whenever the compiler can infer template arguments from the function arguments, it is okay to leave them out. This is also good practice, as it will make your code easier to read.

Also, you can only leave template arguments of the end, not the beginning or middle:

```
template<typename T, typename U> void f(T t) {}
template<typename T, typename U> void g(U u) {}

int main() {
    f<int>(5);      // NOT LEGAL
    f<int, int>(5); // LEGAL

    g<int>(5);      // LEGAL
    g<int, int>(5); // LEGAL

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 11):

There is nothing wrong with calling it with implicit template parameters. The compiler will let you know if it gets confused, in which case you may have to explicitly define the template parameters to call the function.

Comment: Zifre, I think he meant "in which case you may have to explicitly include the template parameters in the function call".

Comment: I don't talk about calling functions explicitly or implicitly I talk about explicitly defining template parameters...

Comment: @DeusAduro Can you explain? I think about how functions will be called, and it motivates my design/definitions. Were you making a semantic distinction or did I misunderstand something?