# Omit template arguments when create an instance of template class from another instance of template class

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, decltype

I want to omit some template parameter `T1,T2` when create an instance of a class `DeriveGenerator<T3,T4,T1,T2>` to comfort my life.

Here is the ultimately simplified version of what I am encountering.

**My library:-**

The important part is the class declaration.   (`this line`)
 Their internal content is just a filler.

```
template<class T1,class T2>class BaseGenerator{ //<-- this line
    public: std::pair<T1*,T2*> generateBase(){ 
        /** actually create T3,T4 internally */
        return std::pair<T1*,T2*>(nullptr,nullptr);
    }
};
template<class T3,class T4,class T1,class T2>class DeriveGenerator{ //<-- this line
    public: Base<T1,T2>* base;
    public: std::pair<T3*,T4*> generateDerive(){ 
        auto pp=base->generateBase();
        return std::pair<T3*,T4*>((T3*)(pp.first),(T4*)(pp.second));
    }
};
```

**User:-**

```
class B1{};class B2{};
class B3:public B1{};
class B4:public B2{};
int main() {
    //v this is what I have to
    BaseGenerator<B1,B2> baseGen;
    DeriveGenerator<B3,B4,B1,B2> deriveGen;  //so dirty #1
    deriveGen.base=&baseGen;
    deriveGen.generateDerive();
}
```

### Question

Is it possible to make the line `#1` cleaner?
I want the type of `deriveGen` **depends on** the type of `baseGen`.

Here is what I wish for :-

```
BaseGenerator<B1,B2> baseGen;
DeriveGenerator<B3,B4> deriveGen;   //<-- modified
deriveGen.base=&baseGen;
```

or at least something like:-

```
BaseGenerator<B1,B2> baseGen;
DeriveGenerator<B3,B4, DECLARATION_TYPE(baseGen) > deriveGen;   //<-- modified
deriveGen.base=&baseGen;
```

I have read (still no clue):-

- [Omitting arguments in C++ Templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1146048/omitting-arguments-in-c-templates)
- [Skipping a C++ template parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276020/skipping-a-c-template-parameter)
- [Difference when omitting the C++ template argument list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3690506/difference-when-omitting-the-c-template-argument-list)

I don't even know if it is possible.

"**decltype**" seems to be the closest clue, but I can't find a way to apply it to this case.
I think I may have to split it to `T1,T2`.... (?)

### **Edit**

In real case, `baseGen` is a non-static field of some classes that is not instantiated yet e.g.

```
class Holder{
    public: BaseGenerator<B1,B2> baseGen;
};
```

Therefore, at the time of declaring `deriveGen`, I can't reach the real instance of `baseGen`.
That is the hard part.

I can refer `baseGen`'s type via `decltype`, though.
(sorry for not mention about it)

Comment: [Food for thought](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1b486a41211de0eb)

Comment: @ildjarn   Your food of thought is so delicious!  Its usefulness is not just a comment-level.  Thank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure to understand what you want but... I suppose you can define `DeriveGenerator` in this way

```
template <typename, typename, typename>
class DeriveGenerator;

template <typename T3, typename T4, typename T1, typename T2>
class DeriveGenerator<T3, T4, BaseGenerator<T1, T2>>
 {
   public:
      BaseGenerator<T1,T2>* base;

   public:
      std::pair<T3*,T4*> generateDerive ()
       { 
         auto pp=base->generateBase();
         return std::pair<T3*,T4*>((T3*)(pp.first),(T4*)(pp.second));
       }
 };
```

and use it as follows

```
BaseGenerator<B1,B2> baseGen;
DeriveGenerator<B3,B4,decltype(baseGen)> deriveGen;
```

This if you're interested in `T1` and `T2` types; if you're only interested in `BaseGenerator<T1, T2>` you can simply write

```
template <typename T3, typename T4, typename Tbase>
class DeriveGenerator
 {
   public:
      Tbase * base;

   public:
      std::pair<T3*,T4*> generateDerive ()
       { 
         auto pp=base->generateBase();
         return std::pair<T3*,T4*>((T3*)(pp.first),(T4*)(pp.second));
       }
 };
```

Comment: What is the line `template <typename, typename, typename>
class DeriveGenerator;` called?  Forward declaration?    I have never known I don't need to fully define the base case.   I just [experiment](http://ideone.com/hoRYNb) about this specifically , and it seems to be compilable.

Comment: @javaLover - if I'm not wrong (but take in count that I'm poor in terminology) is a class "declatarion"; the following `template <typename T3, typename T4, typename T1, typename T2> class DeriveGenerator<T3, T4, BaseGenerator<T1, T2>> { /* ... */ };` is a "definition" of a partial specialization of the class. You don't need the definition of the generic version of the class if the specialization(s) cover all used cases.

Comment: Wow, new knowledge for me.  Thank.

Answer (score 5):

If you can change DeriveGenerator definition to:

```
template<class T3, class T4, class BaseT>
class DeriveGenerator{
public:
    BaseT* base = nullptr;

    std::pair<T3*, T4*> generateDerive(){ 
        auto pp = base->generateBase();
        return {(T3*)(pp.first), (T4*)(pp.second)};
    }
};
```

You might use:

```
BaseGenerator<B1, B2> baseGen;
DeriveGenerator<B3, B4, decltype(baseGen)> deriveGen;
```

Else I suggest to create an helper:

```
 template <typename B3, typename B4, typename B1, typename B2>
 DeriveGenerator<B3, B4, B1, B2>
 MakeDerived(BaseGenerator<B1, B2>& baseGen)
 {
     DeriveGenerator<B3, B4, B1, B2> deriveGen;
     deriveGen.base = &baseGen;
     return deriveGen;
 }
```

and then use

```
BaseGenerator<B1,B2> baseGen;
auto deriveGen = MakeDerived<B3, B4>(baseGen);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, in my case, I can't get an instance of `baseGen` at the time `deriveGen` is declared, and I also want to refer to `B1` and `B2` directly.  Thank.

Comment: You might add `using B1_type = B1;` in `BaseGenerator`, so you might use `BaseT::B1_type` later (as `std::vector<T>::value_type`).

Comment: Else there is still the partial specialization as shown by max66.

Comment: This solution is very useful.  It is pity that I can accept only one solution, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's simpler to push the `T1` and `T2` template parameters for `DeriveGenerator` into the actual `generateDerive` method itself:

```
template<class T3,class T4>
class DeriveGenerator{ 
    public: 
    template<class T1, class T2, template<class, class> class Base>
    std::pair<T3*,T4*> generateDerive(Base<T1, T2>* base){
        static_assert(std::is_base_of<T1, T3>::value && std::is_base_of<T2, T4>::value, "T1 should be base of T3 and T2 should be base of T4"); 
        auto pp=base->generateBase();
        return std::pair<T3*,T4*>((T3*)(pp.first),(T4*)(pp.second));
    }
};
```

### [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1c9c84b3143268b1)

Now you can call it like so:

```
BaseGenerator<B1,B2> baseGen;
DeriveGenerator<B3,B4> deriveGen;
deriveGen.generateDerive(&baseGen);
```

I added a [`static_assert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert) to `DeriveGenerator::generateDerive` that ensured proper base/derived pairing using [`std::is_base_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of) so that you'll get a compiler error if you accidentally mess up the template parameters.

```
class B5{}; // new class B5 nobody inherits from
BaseGenerator<B1, B5> bad_baseGen;
deriveGen.generateDerive(&bad_baseGen);
```

Comment: I don't want to pass `&baseGen` every time, so I have to cache them.  But thank! It is nice to view the problem from another perspective.